# How to access Spring beans away from main class

Tags: java, spring

Most tutorials I've come accross so far access beans from the main class like so:

```
public class JdbcDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        SimpleJdbcDaoImpl dao = ctx.getBean("simpleJdbcDaoImpl", SimpleJdbcDaoImpl.class);

        System.out.println("Circle count from main class is: " + dao.getCircleCount());
    }
}
```

and the SimpleJdbcDaoImpl class:

```
public class SimpleJdbcDaoImpl extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport {

    public int getCircleCount() {
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CIRCLE";
        return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql);
    }
}
```

To access a bean by calling it away from the main class I have to pull so much hustle, like so:

the main class:

```
public class JdbcDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(SomeOtherClass.class).accessSimpleJdbcDaoImpl());
    }
}
```

then in some other class `SomeOtherClass`:

```
@Service
public class SomeOtherClass implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext ac;

    public String accessSimpleJdbcDaoImpl() {
        return "We're getting into some other secondary class.\n" + ac.getBean(SecondaryClass.class).printSecCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
        this.ac = ac;
    }
}
```

and then in `SecondaryClass`

```
@Service
public class SecondaryClass {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJdbcDaoImpl simpleJdbcDaoImpl;

    public String printSecCount() {
       return "Secondary class Circle count is: " + simpleJdbcDaoImpl.getCircleCount();
    }

}
```

This seems to make a project too wired to Spring. Plus in my project there are some beans that I only need in certain classes, so calling them from the main isn't necessary, or just won't work.

Is there a way around going about implementing ApplicationContextAware and not calling them from the main class?

UPDATE:

How can access a class `AwayTest.printAwayTest()` from SecondaryClass below?

```
@Component
public class AwayTest {

    public String printAwayTest() {
        return "Away here\n";
    }

}
```

This doesn't give anything.

```
@Service
public class SecondaryClass {

    @Autowired
    private AwayTest awayTest;

    private SimpleJdbcDaoImpl simpleJdbcDaoImpl;

    @Autowired
    public void setSimpleJdbcDaoImpl(SimpleJdbcDaoImpl impl) {
        simpleJdbcDaoImpl = impl;
    }

    public String printSecCount() {
        return "Away Test: " + awayTest.printAwayTest() + ". Secondary class Circle count is: " + simpleJdbcDaoImpl.getCircleCount();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create proper setters for your dependency injection. If you need an instance of `SimpleJdbcDaoImpl` you shouldn't declare a private autowired field. Instead, create a setter or constructor argument. It will eliminate the dependency on Spring to use reflection to set the field.

```
@Service
public class SomeOtherClass {
    private SecondaryClass secondary;

    @Autowired
    public void setSecondary(SecondaryClass secondary) {
        this.secondary = secondary;
    }

    public String accessSimpleJdbcDaoImpl() {
        return "We're at Some Other Class: " + secondary.printSecCount();
    }
}

@Service
public class SecondaryClass {

    private SimpleJdbcDaoImpl simpleJdbcDaoImpl;

    @Autowired
    public void setSimpleJdbcDaoImpl(SimpleJdbcDaoImpl impl) {
        simpleJdbcDaoImpl = impl;
    }

    public String printSecCount() {
       return "Secondary class Circle count is: " + simpleJdbcDaoImpl.getCircleCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bart for your answer. Would you mind looking at the update above?

Comment: @user3663765 It all works the same. Create a setter for dependency injection. I could write another example but I would be repeating myself :)

Comment: Sorry @Bart. I was going about it wrong. There was something I was not including from your example above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can autowire the private property directly without having the setter and getter methods. Below your codes are correct from my understanding. My suggestion is: check your configuration make sure both AwayTest and SecondaryClass are in the following component-scan base-pakcage:

`<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx.xx" />`

Your codes:

```
@Service public class SecondaryClass {

    @Autowired
    private AwayTest awayTest;

    private SimpleJdbcDaoImpl simpleJdbcDaoImpl;
    .....
```

Comment: Yes you can, but it's not wise. All your classes will be depending on reflection to set a value for that field. That renders the class useless in other projects that don't use the Spring IoC container.

Comment: It will also make it more difficult to test since it's harder to mock dependencies.